# Google Chrome Labs ndb - installs but does not run

Tags: node.js, ndb

I have installed ndb, on Xubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04) according to the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb). I had to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/ndb/issues/20), to get it to install, i.e.

```
sudo npm install -g ndb --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

When I try to, in my project folder, run

```
sudo ndb index.js
```

It reports back

```
Downloading Chromium r624492...
Chromium downloaded to /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ndb/node_modules/carlo/lib/.local-data/linux-624492
```

and I get the command prompt back. Nothing else happens, the UI is not started as expected.

```
sudo ndb.
```

also does nothing. If I try to run either command again, I get

```
    events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at Pipe.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:209:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

So perhaps something has been started but cannot be seen?

What have I missed?